# How to add repeatable component in strapi via HTTP request

Tags: javascript, api, post, strapi

Initially, the messages field (a Strapi repeatable component) will look like this.

```
"messages":[
    {
        "from": "user1",
        "_id": "5f787348628eea0017b49f7e",
        "text": "happy hello world",
        "createdAt": "2020-10-03T12:49:12.052Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-10-03T12:49:12.052Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "id": "5f787348628eea0017b49f7e"
    }
]
```

I want to add another message to the repeatable component:

```
"messages":[
    {
      "from": "user2",
      "text": "happy hello world"
    }
  ]
```

When I Put it via curl:

```
curl -i -X PUT \
   -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
   -d \
'{
  "messages":[
    {
      "from": "shop",
      "text": "happy hello world"
    }
  ]
}' \
 'https://myserver/mes/5f781bdd23e08f001732cdd8'
```

It overwrites the previous message. How do I add the other message without losing any previous data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send all the array with PUT like you did.

```json
{
    "id": "5f781bdd23e08f001732cdd8",
    "messages": [
        {
            "id": "5f787348628eea0017b49f7e",
            "from": "user1",
            "text": "happy hello world"
        },
        {

            "from": "shop",
            "text": "happy hello world"
        }
    ]
}
```

Looks like Strapi can't know if you want to update the first, or delete it, or create a new one ...

Comment: i have found that i have to send entire contents of a particular field, found it on strapi docs

Comment: Sorry, I missunderstood your question, I edit my response.

Comment: @lascapi It appears that if I send multiple concurrent PUT requests with a full array to that endpoint then there is an error that occurs due to a mismatch in the data. I am using grapql and when I send it two request at the same time I get this error `"No matching document found for id \"602ea4add988a28e57fb355a\" version 5 modifiedPaths \"messages\"",`. It also appears as though sending an empty array to "messages" will wipe out the entire repeatable component, are there any guardrails to prevent that? Maybe I should just not use a repeatable component.