# Prevent a repeatable component on Strapi from being deleted by passing an empty array in the Repeater Field mutation?

Tags: graphql, strapi

What would be the best way to prevent a repeatable component on Strapi from being inadvertently deleted by passing an empty array in the mutation?

As an example, I have the following Collection Type:

```
  "kind": "collectionType",
  "collectionName": "books",
  "info": {
    "name": "Books"
  },
  "options": {
    "increments": true,
    "timestamps": true
  },
  "attributes": {
    "pages": {
      "type": "component",
      "repeatable": true,
      "component": "page.pages"
    }
  }
}
```

If I have passed in an empty array for the repeatable fields (pages) then it appears to remove the entire repeatable component. For context, I want users to be able to update the elements in the repeatable component but restrict wiping everything out. Per this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64184553/how-to-add-repeatable-component-in-strapi-via-http-request), it appears I have to send in the entire array in the mutation or put request. What I don't want is for someone to send an empty array and delete everything.

```
mutation {
    updateBook(input: {
        where: { id: "602ea4add988a28e57fb355a" },
        data: {
            pages: []
        }
    }){
        book {
            id
            pages {
                text
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Aparently you have to query the data on the component and then add it again with the new entry

"in strapi groups i can't just add the new entry, i have to include all previous ones or otherwise they will be deleted !
currently to update an entry in a group you have to use the parent update(), or there is an other way ?"

*Originally posted by @bouhendfaycal in https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/4590#issuecomment-558741136*